# Pig referencing

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am learning Hadoop pig and I always stuck at referencing the elements.please find the below example.

```
groupwordcount: {group: chararray,words: {(bag_of_tokenTuples_from_line::token: chararray)}}
```

Can somebody please explain how to reference the elements if we have nested tuples and bags.

Any Links for better understanding the nested referrencing would be great help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a simple Demonstration to understand this problem.

say a file  'a.txt' stored at '/tmp/a.txt' folder in HDFS

**A = LOAD '/tmp/a.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,term:chararray,gpa:float);**

**Dump A;**

(John,fl,3.9)

(John,fl,3.7)

(John,sp,4.0)

(John,sm,3.8)

(Mary,fl,3.8)

(Mary,fl,3.9)

(Mary,sp,4.0)

(Mary,sm,4.0)

Now let's group by this Alias 'A' on the basis of some parameter say name and term

**B = GROUP A BY (name,term);**

**dump B;**

((John,fl),{(John,fl,3.7),(John,fl,3.9)})

((John,sm),{(John,sm,3.8)})

((John,sp),{(John,sp,4.0)})

((Mary,fl),{(Mary,fl,3.9),(Mary,fl,3.8)})

((Mary,sm),{(Mary,sm,4.0)})

((Mary,sp),{(Mary,sp,4.0)})

**describe B;**

**B: {group: (name: chararray,term: chararray),A: {(name: chararray,term: chararray,gpa: float)}}**

now it has become the problem statement that you have asked. Let me demonstrate you how to access elements of group tuple or element of A tuple or both

**C = foreach B generate group.name,group.term,A.name,A.term,A.gpa;**

**dump C;**

(John,fl,{(John),(John)},{(fl),(fl)},{(3.7),(3.9)})

(John,sm,{(John)},{(sm)},{(3.8)})

(John,sp,{(John)},{(sp)},{(4.0)})

(Mary,fl,{(Mary),(Mary)},{(fl),(fl)},{(3.9),(3.8)})

(Mary,sm,{(Mary)},{(sm)},{(4.0)})

(Mary,sp,{(Mary)},{(sp)},{(4.0)})

So we accessed all elements by this way.

**hope this helped**