# Extract single value from Tuple after aggregation using pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I am getting output of my *group by* as expected.

```
((USD),{(6/14/2017),(6/14/2017)},{(IM),(IM)},{(Non-Net),(Non-Net)},{(Gross),(Gross)};
```

This is the result of aggregation of 2 rows.

**Expected Output**:

```
((USD),{(6/14/2017)},{(IM)},{(Non-Net)},{(Gross)};
```

I am using the below code snippet:

```
data_load = load 'input.txt' using PigStorage(',') As (a:chararray,b:chararray,c:chararray,d:chararray,e:chararray);

aggregate_by = GROUP data_load BY a;

results = FOREACH aggregate_by GENERATE group as a;
DUMP results;
```

Comment: Show initial data and the code you applied to it.

Comment: Please post your pig script..clearly specify what u want to achieve

Comment: please share your alias on which you have done group by. If you want to learn referencing in pig . this link might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490831/pig-referencing/44494850#44494850

Comment: Can anyone please help!